# Get email address using Facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get email address from facebok login.

Please see the code

```
    <?php

    // added in v4.0.0
    require_once 'autoload.php';

    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
    // init app with app id and secret
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $fb_app,$fb_key );
    // login helper with redirect_uri
      $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://my-site.com/fbconfig.php' );
    try {
      $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
      // When Facebook returns an error
    } catch( Exception $ex ) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
    }
    // see if we have a session
    if ( isset( $session ) ) {
      // graph api request for user data
      $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
      $response = $request->execute();
      // get response
      $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
            $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
            $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('first_name');
            $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
        /* ---- Session Variables -----*/



    } else {
      $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
     header("Location: index.html");
    }

?>
```

everything seems to be working fine except for the email.

I'm using the line `$femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');`to get the email address of the user.

Can someone point me how to fix this issue?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes, “Declarative Fields”

Comment: @CBroe if it works for the first name field, it means the problem is not related to declarative fields (probably an old version of the SDK that default Graph API version to a lower one). The email field needs to be authorized by the user with it dedicated permission, but I guess you already know that :)

Answer (score 1):

You should ask for the `email` permission (the scope parameter) when you get the login URL. The user need to grant you access to his/her email adress.